# Unable to set my attached property unless it is in a style setter

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties, wpf-style

I have an assembly with a custom Control class the defines an attached property.

```
public class LayerView : MultiSelector
{   
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            nameof(PathStyle),
            typeof(Style),
            typeof(LayerView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));


    public Style PathStyle
    {
        get => (Style)GetValue(PathStyleProperty);
        set => SetValue(PathStyleProperty, value);
    }

    //...etc. etc -- this is a 2,000 lines of code)

}
```

Later on, in another assembly I try to set this attached property on another custom control in a `DataTemplate`.

```
<Style x:Key="OverlayLayerControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ana:LineProperty}">
            <!-- ERROR -- cannot Set attached property this way -->
            <ctrl:LineControl                    
                P1="{Binding ValueT.P1}" P2="{Binding ValueT.P2}"
                TextElement.FontSize="20"
                ctrl:LayerView.PathStyle="{StaticResource OutputPathStyle}"/> 

        </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>

</Style>
```

It does not even build.   It gives me build error MC3015

> 7>C:\Users\jmole\source\repos\Main\Mobile.Common\Resources\CommonLayerViewStyles.xaml(430,21):
> error MC3015: The attached property 'LayerView.PathStyle' is not
> defined on 'LineControl' or one of its base classes.

And that's true.  It is not *supposed* to be in LineControl.  It is an attached property.

So why am I, above, able to set another attached property like `TextElement.FontSize` but not my own property?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56044088/5869304) which made me think I might just need to set the property in the *body* of the element to make it work.  I tried that but I got the exact same error

In desperation I tried setting same attached property in regular setter in the style.  So I'm setting it on the `ItemsControl`, not the items within it.

```
    <!-- This works just fine -->
    
    <Setter Property="ctrl:LayerView.PathStyle" Value="{StaticResource OutputPathStyle}"/>
```

This builds and runs and functions correctly.  Since the `PathStyle` property inherits, child items do receive it.  But I need to be able to set this property in individual items, not the whole layer.

So what did I get wrong wrong with my `PathStyle` property that I cannot set it like `TextElement.FontSize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that your accessors for the attached property are not static.

Try this:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty PathStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        nameof(PathStyle),
        typeof(Style),
        typeof(LayerView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


// Declare static get/set accessor methods
public static Style GetPathStyle(UIElement target) =>
    (Style)target.GetValue(PathStyleProperty);
public static void SetPathStyle(UIElement target, Style value) =>
    target.SetValue(PathStyleProperty, value);
```

Comment: That was it exactly.   I missed that little rule.  Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Glad that did it